# compile jruby files to a different directory

Tags: ruby, jruby

I have a jruby application in the following folder structure :

```
lib/*.class files
src/*.rb files
```

I want to compile all the .rb files in `src` using `jrubyc *.rb` and have it automatically moved to `lib` after the compiling all the files.

Is there a way to specify a 'target' directory for all my newly compiled `.class` files?

I have looked at `jruby -help` but cannot find an option for that.

Answer (score 0):

try running `**jrubyc** --help` ... you should get :

```
jrubyc [options] (FILE|DIRECTORY)

  -d, --dir DIR            Use DIR as the base path
  -p, --prefix PREFIX      Prepend PREFIX to the file path and package. Default is no prefix.
  -t, --target TARGET      Output files to TARGET directory
  -J OPTION                Pass OPTION to javac for javac compiles
      --java               Generate Java classes (.java) for a script containing Ruby class definitions
      --javac              Generate Java classes (.java and .class) for a script containing Ruby class definitions
  -c CLASSPATH,            Add a jar to the classpath for building
      --classpath
      --sha1               Compile to a class named using the SHA1 hash of the source file
      --handles            Also generate all direct handle classes for the source file
      --verbose            Log verbose output while compile
```

so you'll need to specify `--target TARGET/DIR`